# Active menu not stay active and highlight

Tags: php, html, css, jquery-ui, navbar

Please someone help me. Im new to coding, I'm trying to highlight the active menu item. I have been searching for almost two weeks, but it is still not resolved. I have tried with Jquery CDN; it works, but when I upload all this to the web, it doesn't work. When I click the menu, it highlights, then disappears suddenly. So it didn't work with Jquery CDN.

here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Home</title>
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  
  </head>
<body class="dahshat-board">

    <div id="main-wrap">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                        
          <div class="sidebar-pinner">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="scrollNav">


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse mobileNav" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                          <li class="active" ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="nav-bottom">
      <div class="container">
          <ul class="nav page-navigation">
                                    <li class="active" ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                    
                                                                              </ul>
          </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Main variables *content* --> 
  


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#toi").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#main-wrap").toggleClass("launched");
  });
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $('#main-wrap').removeClass('launched');
    $(".mobileSearch a").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".search-bar").toggleClass("toggleSearch");
    });
  } else {
    $('#main-wrap').addClass('launched');
  }
  /*$(window).scroll(function() {
      var nav = $('#scrollNav');
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 10) {
          nav.addClass('fixedNav');
      } else {
          nav.removeClass('fixedNav');
      }
  });*/
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

here is the css

```
}
.dahshat-board .navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: none;
}
.nav-bottom {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
.nav.page-navigation {
    background: #fad534;
    border-radius: 500px;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.08);
    justify-content: center;
}
.nav.page-navigation li {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: auto;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 0 0 10.85%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.nav-bottom .nav .dropdown li {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    text-align: left;
}
.nav-bottom .nav li .ico {
    margin-right: 4px;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    background: #2b1f60;
    border-color: #2b1f60;
}
.nav-bottom .nav li.active .ico {
    background: #fad534;
    border-color: #fad534;
}
.nav-bottom .nav li.active .ico img {
    filter: invert(1) brightness(100%) saturate(0);
}
.nav-bottom .nav li a {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 44px;
    color: #2a1e5e;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2px 9px;
    border-radius: 500px;
    white-space: pre;
    width:100%;
}
.nav-bottom .nav li.dropdown.open a.dropdown-toggle {
    /* background: transparent;
    border: none; */
}
.nav-bottom .nav li a:hover,
.nav-bottom .nav li a:active,
.nav-bottom .nav li a:focus {
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
}
.nav-bottom .nav .dropdown li a {
    line-height: 18px;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.nav-bottom .nav .dropdown li a .badge {
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    top: 13px;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.nav-bottom .nav li.active a {
    color: #fad534;
    background-color: #270044;
}
.nav-bottom .nav .dropdown li a::after,
.nav-bottom .nav .dropdown li a::before {
    display: none;
}
```

please help

Comment: if the above is the actual HTML markup you are using then I am basically not surprised that you cannot get your javascript function to work or the css... that is not valid markup ~ not even close. Honestly - the best thing you can learn when new to HTML is proper indentation and following the rules regarding opening/closing of tags and not `straddling` elements

Comment: please be kind enough to correct the incorrect lines?

Comment: see below... it validates correctly now

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer as such but I corrected your HTML markup as best I could - it now validates correctly so that in itself might be a help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' />
        <meta name='keywords' content='' />
        <meta name='description' content='' />
    </head>
    <body class="dahshat-board">
    
        <div id="main-wrap">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default ">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                    
                        <!--///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        
                            The element "button" must not appear as a descendant of the "a" element.
                            The hyperlink has been removed from the DOM which might affect your 
                            layout
                        
                        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
                        <!--
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"></a>
                        -->
                        
                        <div class="sidebar-pinner">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        
                        
                        <div id="scrollNav">
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse mobileNav" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li class="active" ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                                    
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="nav-bottom">
                            <div class="container">
                                <ul class="nav page-navigation">
                                    <li class="active" ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
                    
                    
        <!-- Main variables *content* -->
        <script src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js'></script>
        <script>
        
            $('#toi').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#main-wrap').toggleClass('launched');
            });

            if ($(window).width() < 768) {
                $('#main-wrap').removeClass('launched');
                $('.mobileSearch a').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('.search-bar').toggleClass('toggleSearch');
                });
            } else {
                $('#main-wrap').addClass('launched');
            }
        </script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

The original code, run through the W3c validator produced the following results... as you will see it gave up hope and bailed!

[image: W3c Validator results]

If the markup alters the layout significantly look again at the css and judge whether the above markup was your intended layout. With valid markup you should have fewer problems going forward I hope.

Comment: glad I was able to offer some help.